# How to replace a select tag when sibling is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three (cascading) select tags that appear one after another in a div. The html for them only differ in the options. The name and ids of the select are the same.

```
<div class="dad">
  <select id="foo" name="foo[bar]" value="myVal">
    ...
    <option value="343">boom</option>
    ...
  </select>
  <select id="foo" name="foo[bar]" value="myVal">...</select>
  <select id="foo" name="foo[bar]" value="myVal">...</select>
</div>
```

The behavior I need is when a select is changed, an ajax call is made which provides the data (markup) for the next select. The data I get back which is markup a select and it's options is fine but am having issues replacing the next select.

```
$('select#foo').live("change", function() {

    var optionSelected = $('option:selected', this);
    var selID = optionSelected.val();

    $.post('/postUrl?data=selID', function(data) {
      // need to replace the second select
    });
    ...
```

Usually I would have the id or class of the select I need to replace and would be easy. THe issue here is since all three select have the same id and name how can i identify the select after the one that is selected? Thanks.

Comment: `id` should be unique for each element.

Comment: @absolutskyy - I'm curious..why do all select tags have the same name/id? Is this something you can control? If it is, you should make them unique asap..otherwise, you'll continue to have problems like this as your project grows.

Comment: You're very right. The selects were being metaprogrammed which was not working the way it should but I've now changed the selects to have distinct IDs so this makes it super easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this..

```
$('select#foo').live("change", function() {

    var optionSelected = $('option:selected', this);
    var selID = optionSelected.val();
    var nextSelect = $(this).next();

    $.post('/postUrl?data=selID', function(data) {
      // do action with nextSelect
      nextSelect.doSomething;
    });
```

Comment: thanks @dipen appreciate the help. Please see my comment above.